# CSS animation to move eyes from left to right alternative

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions, css-transforms

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

#eyes {
  animation: sun-eyes 2s ease infinite;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes sun-eyes {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-350px, 0)
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="20%" height="70vh" viewBox="0 0 1274 754" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="sunfigma 1">
      <g id="sunbody">
        <path id="Vector" d="M62.4028 749.792H1274" stroke="black" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_2"
          d="M656.983 237.831C646.606 237.831 636.313 238.251 626.132 239.009C623.327 239.233 620.523 239.486 617.718 239.766C559.204 245.604 502.707 264.321 452.278 294.575C401.85 324.828 358.739 365.869 326.039 414.754C293.339 463.639 271.859 519.156 263.14 577.323C254.422 635.491 258.68 694.867 275.61 751.195H1038.47C1056.36 691.685 1060.08 628.816 1049.36 567.608C1038.63 506.399 1013.74 448.548 976.686 398.672C939.628 348.796 891.425 308.277 835.925 280.35C780.425 252.423 719.166 237.863 657.039 237.831H656.983Z"
          fill="url(#paint0_linear)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_3" d="M235.42 101.915L370.491 246.976" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"
          stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_4" d="M764.568 178.415L825.569 0.925781" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"
          stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_5" d="M1094.08 389.624L1235.74 294.188" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"
          stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_6" d="M1140.67 730.857L1251.28 739.3" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_7" d="M0.701172 558.95L164.744 601.253" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"
          stroke-miterlimit="10" />
      </g>
      <g id="eyes">
        <path id="Vector_8"
          d="M724.294 690.881C730.49 690.881 735.512 685.858 735.512 679.66C735.512 673.463 730.49 668.439 724.294 668.439C718.098 668.439 713.075 673.463 713.075 679.66C713.075 685.858 718.098 690.881 724.294 690.881Z"
          fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_9"
          d="M837.881 681.063C837.881 684.039 836.699 686.893 834.595 688.998C832.491 691.102 829.638 692.284 826.663 692.284C820.464 692.284 815.444 685.86 815.444 679.66C815.444 673.461 820.464 669.842 826.663 669.842C829.638 669.842 832.491 671.024 834.595 673.129C836.699 675.233 837.881 678.087 837.881 681.063Z"
          fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="363" y1="-78" x2="863" y2="1098" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop stop-color="#FFDB00" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFDB00" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
  </svg>


</body>

</html>
```

**How can I move the eyeballs directly from left to right and right to left alternatively without showing the moving transition of eye balls and keeping the position fairly correct?**

I'm completely newbie to CSS animations. Any help would be appreciated! I have added the code snippet as much as I could experiment with it.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't it do that already?

Comment: @keyframes sun-eyes {
0%{}
50%{}
75%{}
100%{}
}

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan No, It moves the object and shows it's path. I need eyes to move directly to right side.  For your reference , http://www.spacedout.com.hk/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/weather-sunrise.gif have a look on this.

Comment: change 2s to 0s in `animation: sun-eyes 2s ease infinite`.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul That wouldn't even move the eyess.

Comment: Why dont you try to make a second block eye with a position on left and you play with display none / display block animation ?

Comment: @MaxiGui Looks like a good idea... will try

Comment: https://codepen.io/knudsem/pen/OJyNwwM

I made something similar few weeks ago. You just have to select the dots of the eyeball and move it with keyframes translate

Answer (score 2):

Simply like below with no complex JS code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

#eyes {
  animation: sun-eyes 2s ease infinite;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes sun-eyes {
  0%,50% {
    transform: translate(100px, 0)
  }
  50.1%,100% {
    transform: translate(-350px, 0)
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="20%" height="70vh" viewBox="0 0 1274 754" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="sunfigma 1">
      <g id="sunbody">
        <path id="Vector" d="M62.4028 749.792H1274" stroke="black" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_2"
          d="M656.983 237.831C646.606 237.831 636.313 238.251 626.132 239.009C623.327 239.233 620.523 239.486 617.718 239.766C559.204 245.604 502.707 264.321 452.278 294.575C401.85 324.828 358.739 365.869 326.039 414.754C293.339 463.639 271.859 519.156 263.14 577.323C254.422 635.491 258.68 694.867 275.61 751.195H1038.47C1056.36 691.685 1060.08 628.816 1049.36 567.608C1038.63 506.399 1013.74 448.548 976.686 398.672C939.628 348.796 891.425 308.277 835.925 280.35C780.425 252.423 719.166 237.863 657.039 237.831H656.983Z"
          fill="url(#paint0_linear)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_3" d="M235.42 101.915L370.491 246.976" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"
          stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_4" d="M764.568 178.415L825.569 0.925781" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"
          stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_5" d="M1094.08 389.624L1235.74 294.188" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"
          stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_6" d="M1140.67 730.857L1251.28 739.3" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_7" d="M0.701172 558.95L164.744 601.253" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"
          stroke-miterlimit="10" />
      </g>
      <g id="eyes">
        <path id="Vector_8"
          d="M724.294 690.881C730.49 690.881 735.512 685.858 735.512 679.66C735.512 673.463 730.49 668.439 724.294 668.439C718.098 668.439 713.075 673.463 713.075 679.66C713.075 685.858 718.098 690.881 724.294 690.881Z"
          fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_9"
          d="M837.881 681.063C837.881 684.039 836.699 686.893 834.595 688.998C832.491 691.102 829.638 692.284 826.663 692.284C820.464 692.284 815.444 685.86 815.444 679.66C815.444 673.461 820.464 669.842 826.663 669.842C829.638 669.842 832.491 671.024 834.595 673.129C836.699 675.233 837.881 678.087 837.881 681.063Z"
          fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="363" y1="-78" x2="863" y2="1098" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop stop-color="#FFDB00" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFDB00" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
  </svg>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it using a bit of javascipt/jquery to create some timed events happening inside a loop.

```js
let eyes = $("#eyes");
function LoopForever() {
setTimeout(function() { $(eyes).css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(-350px, 0)'); }, 1000);
setTimeout(function() { $(eyes).css('display', 'none'); }, 2000);
setTimeout(function() { $(eyes).css('display', 'block'); }, 2300);
setTimeout(function() { $(eyes).css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(100px, 0)'); }, 3300);
setTimeout(function() { $(eyes).css('display', 'none'); }, 4300);
setTimeout(function() { $(eyes).css('display', 'block'); }, 4500);
}
var interval = self.setInterval(function(){LoopForever()},7000);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="20%" height="70vh" viewBox="0 0 1274 754" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="sunfigma 1">
      <g id="sunbody">
        <path id="Vector" d="M62.4028 749.792H1274" stroke="black" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_2"
          d="M656.983 237.831C646.606 237.831 636.313 238.251 626.132 239.009C623.327 239.233 620.523 239.486 617.718 239.766C559.204 245.604 502.707 264.321 452.278 294.575C401.85 324.828 358.739 365.869 326.039 414.754C293.339 463.639 271.859 519.156 263.14 577.323C254.422 635.491 258.68 694.867 275.61 751.195H1038.47C1056.36 691.685 1060.08 628.816 1049.36 567.608C1038.63 506.399 1013.74 448.548 976.686 398.672C939.628 348.796 891.425 308.277 835.925 280.35C780.425 252.423 719.166 237.863 657.039 237.831H656.983Z"
          fill="url(#paint0_linear)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_3" d="M235.42 101.915L370.491 246.976" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"
          stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_4" d="M764.568 178.415L825.569 0.925781" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"
          stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_5" d="M1094.08 389.624L1235.74 294.188" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"
          stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_6" d="M1140.67 730.857L1251.28 739.3" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_7" d="M0.701172 558.95L164.744 601.253" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"
          stroke-miterlimit="10" />
      </g>
      <g id="eyes">
        <path id="Vector_8"
          d="M724.294 690.881C730.49 690.881 735.512 685.858 735.512 679.66C735.512 673.463 730.49 668.439 724.294 668.439C718.098 668.439 713.075 673.463 713.075 679.66C713.075 685.858 718.098 690.881 724.294 690.881Z"
          fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
        <path id="Vector_9"
          d="M837.881 681.063C837.881 684.039 836.699 686.893 834.595 688.998C832.491 691.102 829.638 692.284 826.663 692.284C820.464 692.284 815.444 685.86 815.444 679.66C815.444 673.461 820.464 669.842 826.663 669.842C829.638 669.842 832.491 671.024 834.595 673.129C836.699 675.233 837.881 678.087 837.881 681.063Z"
          fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="363" y1="-78" x2="863" y2="1098" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop stop-color="#FFDB00" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFDB00" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
  </svg>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why the animation starts after waiting for some minutes and not instantly? Unable to fix that

Comment: it shouldn't wait for minutes but about 7 seconds. did you change any of the code?

Comment: Yes I want it as preloader, so messing it up so that it doesnt wait for any seconds

Comment: I get that part that the process repeats after every 7 seconds but I want it to be played as soon as the page loads